# Get Value between div class tag with HTMLAgility

Tags: asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

Trying to get value between 'statusType' tag with no success using htmlagility pack

html:

```
<div class="statusLabel">Status:</div>
<div class="statusType">Printing in 20 minutes                                              
</div>
```

code:

```
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(xmldoc.OuterXml.ToString)
Dim divNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='statusType']")
```

I know this is simple could anyone help?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the error that you're getting or the rest of your HTML document, it's hard to help, but you might try changing your XPath to `//div[@class='statusType']`.  This finds all `div`s in the document with a class attribute equal to statusType.

Notes:

1. `//` selector can be expensive performance-wise on large documents.
2. `@class='statusType'` won't match if additional classes are present in
   the attribute value; consider `contains(@class, 'statusType')`.
3. Be careful of case where more than one matching `div` may exist in the
   document.  `SelectSingleNode` will chose the first, and it may not be
   the one you have in mind.